# Problema con el elemento 0 de un arreglo en c

Tags: array, c

Tengo un `for` que guarda números en el arreglo, a la hora de imprimirlo los demás salen bien pero el elemento 0 del arreglo imprime un cero, no se a que se deba. Es en el caso de base 16, según yo esta bien todo. No se si puedan también ayudarme en convertir la parte fraccionaria del decimal.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10000

int Menu();
void TransformarBase(int op, double num);



int main(){
double num=0;
int op;


do{
    op=Menu(); 
    if(op!=6){
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\tIngresa el numero que quieras convertir: "); 
 scanf("%lf", &num);
    TransformarBase(op,num);        
    }
    
}while(op!=6);

return 0;   
}

int Menu(){

int opcion;

system("cls");
printf("\n\n\n\n");
printf("\t\t\tElige a que base quieres convertir tu numero\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t1.-BASE 02\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t2.-BASE 05\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t3.-BASE 09\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t4.-BASE 16\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t5.-BASE 23\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t6.-SALIR\n\n");
do{
printf("\t\t\tOpcion: "); scanf("%d", &opcion);
printf("\n\t\t\tERROR opcion invalida, ingrese una nueva\n\n");
}while( opcion<1 || opcion>6 );
system("cls");

return opcion;          
}

void TransformarBase(int opcion, double num){
int cociente, residuo; 
int cont, i;
int conv[MAX];
i=0;
switch(opcion){
    case 1: //Base 02
        do{
        cociente = num/2;
        residuo = (int)num%2;
        conv[i] = residuo;
        num = cociente;
        i++;
        }while (cociente>0);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tLa conversion en base 02 es: ");
        for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--)
        {
        printf("%d", conv [cont]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
    break;

    case 2: //Base 05
        do{
        cociente = num/5;
        residuo = (int)num%5;
        conv[i] = residuo;
        num = cociente;
        i++;
        }while (cociente>0);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tLa conversion en base 05 es: ");
        for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--)
        {
        printf("%d", conv [cont]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
    break;
    
    case 3: //Base 09
        do{
        cociente = num/9;
        residuo = (int)num%9;
        conv[i] = residuo;
        num = cociente;
        i++;
        }while (cociente>0);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tLa conversion en base 09 es: ");
        for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--)
        {
        printf("%d", conv [cont]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
    break;
    
    case 4: //Base 16   
        i=0;
        do{
        cociente = num/16;
        residuo = (int)num%16;
        conv[i] = residuo;
        num = cociente;
        i+=1;
        }while (cociente>0);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tLa conversion en base 16 es: ");
        for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--){
        if(conv[cont] == 10){
            printf("A");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 11){
            printf("B");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 12){
            printf("C");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 13){
            printf("D");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 14){
            printf("E");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 15){
            printf("F");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d", conv [cont]);
        }   
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
    break;
    
    case 5: //Base 23 
        do{
        cociente = num/23;
        residuo = (int)num%23;
        conv[i] = residuo;
        num = cociente;
        i+=1;
        }while (cociente>0);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\tLa conversion en base 23 es: ");
        for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--){
        if(conv[cont] == 10){
            printf("A");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 11){
            printf("B");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 12){
            printf("C");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 13){
            printf("D");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 14){
            printf("E");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 15){
            printf("F");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 16){
            printf("G");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 17){
            printf("H");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 18){
            printf("I");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 19){
            printf("J");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 20){
            printf("K");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 21){
            printf("L");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 22){
            printf("M");
        }
        else if(conv[cont] == 23){
            printf("N");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d", conv [cont]);
        }   
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
    break;
    
    default:
        printf("Opcion NO valida\n\n");
        system("pause");
    break;
    }       
    }
```

Comment: perdon ya lo subi

Comment: ya lo cambie :c

Comment: ¿Te diste cuenta que el código en el switch es prácticamente el mismo para todo? Bueno, ten en cuenta eso para simplificarlo. Puedes hacer lo mismo con menos líneas de código.

Comment: no sabia que se puede simplificar

Answer (score 0):

Como sugerí en los comentarios, puedes usar el mismo código para convertir a cualquier base ya que el procedimiento es el mismo. Eso ya lo sabes.

Solo debes hacer algunos cambios:

```
void TransformarBase(int num, int base){
    if (base < 2){
        printf ("La base debe ser mayor o igual a 2\n");
        return;
    }
    int max = 64;
    char conv[max + 1] = "";

    int i = max - 1;

    do{
        int resto = num % base;
        char digito = resto + '0';
        if (resto >= 10)
             digito = resto - 10 + 'A';

        conv[i] = digito;
        i--;

        num /= base;
    } while (num > 0);
    printf("\n");
    printf("La conversion en base %d es: %s", base, &conv[i + 1]);
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
}
```

En lugar de conservar los restos, los conviertes directamente en un carácter y guardas de atrás para adelante así puedes imprimirlos como una cadena de texto.

Este algoritmo aprovecha el uso de una codificación basada en ASCII donde los dígitos son contiguos y las letras también. Si ese no fuera el caso, podrías hacer una pequeña modificación:

```
void TransformarBase(int num, int base){
    if (base < 2){
        printf("La base debe ser mayor o igual a 2\n");
        return;
    }
    int max = 64;
    char conv[max + 1] = "";

    char digitos[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i = max - 1;

    do{
        int resto = num % base;
        conv[i] = digitos[resto];
        i--;

        num /= base;
    } while (num > 0);
    printf("\n");
    printf("La conversion en base %d es: %s", base, &conv[i + 1]);
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Por cierto, la cadena tiene un elemento extra para el caracter nulo. 64 dígitos me parece bien ya que un procesador actual es de 64 bits y no puedes trabajar con números más grandes.